# Render cache if cache is exists, if not render nothing with Symfony

Tags: php, caching, symfony1

What I'm trying to do is render either a partial or a fragment in Symfony from the cache (the easy part) but if the cache does not exist, then I want Symfony to (instead of recreating the cache) render nothing.

My website pulls data from multiple other websites, which can insanely slow down page rendering speed, so instead of loading the info from other websites on the initial page load, I plan on doing it once the initial page is finished loading and a user clicks the appropriate button, then caching the data for later. However, if the data is cached (from a previous request) then I would rather dump the cached data right into the initial page load.

I tried to clarify it as much as possible, so hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you could handle this with a filter and the getViewCacheManager()